# Post editor doesn't save embed media

Tags: save-post, embed, post-editor, youtube

I'm facing weird problem - I'm trying to save embed media to post in different computers and it doesn't work in all of them.

We do the same process (insert -> media -> embed -> youtube code), and in one computer it work and in the other it doesn't.

I've no idea what do, what can cause this weird problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was permissions to Administrator and Editor of editing `HTML`. In multisite those permissions are gone - so I've installed `Unfilterd MU` plugin and its solved.